# Tossing Until First Heads Outcome, and Repeating, as a Method for Estimating Probability of Heads

Tags: expected-value, bias, estimators, unbiased-estimator

Consider the problem of estimating the heads probability $p$ of a coin
by tossing it until the first heads outcome is observed. Say we get $k_1$
tosses, then $U_1 = \frac{1}{k_1}$ is an estimate for $p$. It can be shown that
$E(U_1) > p,$ assuming $p < 1$ (eg by working the expression for the expectation, or via Jensen's inequality).  I am interested in certain extensions (to be explained next), and whether there are good references (papers/lectures or books, hopefully publicly accessible!) that might contain such results (or perhaps proof techniques for such).

In particular, we want to improve our estimate and imagine we repeat
the experiment $j \ge 1$ times, and we
get $k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_j$  tosses (on the $i$th experiment, $k_i$ tosses are
performed until a heads is observed). We  define $U_j = \frac{j}{\sum_{i
\le j} k_i}$. My conjecture is that $U_j$ are upper estimates, and $L_j =
\frac{j-1}{\sum_{i \le j} k_i}$ are lower estimates (and that the estimates
improve with increasing $j$, that is $\forall j \ge 1, E(U_{j}) > E(U_{j+1}) > p > E(L_{j+1}) > E(L_{j})$, and empirical simulations provide evidence).

I have also seen that $\frac{1}{k_1+k_2-1}$ is an unbiased estimate of $p$ (which establishes most parts of the above conjectures for $j \le 2$).  So
another question is whether there exist unbiased estimators for higher
$j$.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Omid! Could you please explain what you mean by upper and lower estimates? Do you mean that the true value *never* is above the upper estimate or below the lower estimate, or is it just the equations $E(U_j)>p$ and $E(L_j)<p$?

Comment: Thanks much Ute @Ute! Sorry: I just meant in the sense of the latter, that is the inequalities you gave on the expectations. And I just noticed I forgot to put the expectations on $U_i$ and $L_i$! (I'll try to fix the post. Many thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your experiments generates an observation from a Geometric distribution with probability parameter $p$.  There are two forms of the Geometric; one which includes the "final" flip, i.e., the heads, in the count, and which therefore has a minimum value of $1$, and one which does not.

Adopting the first form, we have the maximum likelihood estimate:

$$\hat{p} = {j \over \sum_{i=1}^j k_i}$$

which as you have observed has expectation $\mathbb{E}\hat{p} > p$.

The Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator (MVUE) of $p$ given $j$ observations is:

$$p^* = {j-1 \over (\sum_{i=1}^jk_i) - 1}$$

as derived at some length in [A Geometric Approach to Conditioning and the Search for Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimators](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=110122#:%7E:text=One%20way%20to%20find%20an%20unbiased%20estimator%20of,%3E%201%20is%20an%20unbiased%20estimator%20of%20%CE%B8.).  Clearly $p^* >$ your $ L_j$, establishing that $L_j$ is indeed biased low, and, as
$j \leq \sum k_i$, $$p^* = {j-1 \over \sum k_i - 1} \leq {j \over\sum k_i} = U_j$$ establishing that $U_j$ is biased high.

Edit with outline of proof of the MVUE property of $p^*$:

We will use the [Rao-Blackwell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem) combined with a) an unbiased estimator of $p$ and b) a sufficient statistic in a process known as [Rao-Blackwellization](https://andrewcharlesjones.github.io/journal/rao-blackwellization.html) to generate the MVUE of $p$.

Our unbiased estimator is $\hat{\theta}_1 = 1(k_1=1)$, where $1(a)$ is the indicator function that takes on the value $1$ if $a$ is true and $0$ otherwise.  This is clearly unbiased, but not very good, as it only looks at the first one of the $k_i$ and ignores the rest.

Our sufficient statistic is based on the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^j k_i \sim \text{Negative Binomial}(j,p)$, a well-known result.  The sufficient statistic for the N.B. distribution with known shape parameter is known to be $y=\sum k_i$, and we won't show that here.

Now we need to find $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}_1|y)$, which Rao-Blackwell tells us is the MVUE estimator of $p$.

$$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}_1|y) = p(k_1 = 1|y) = p(k_1=1 | y, k_n=1) = {j-1\over y-1} $$

where the second equality comes from the fact that the *last* coin flip is known to be a head from the structure of the experiment, and the final equality from the fact that this leaves $j-1$ heads spread out randomly amongst the $y-1$ unaccounted-for tosses; as the flips are exchangeable, the probability that the first flip - i.e., $\hat{\theta}_1$ - equals $1$ is just $(j-1)/(y-1)$, and this is also its expected value.

Comment: Much appreciated: This is exactly what I was looking for! (simulations point to accuracy of the claim too, and I am trying to understand the paper to the extent I can!)  I am writing a paper using this technique, and wonder if I can acknowledge you, @jbowman, there! Many thanks.

Comment: Sure!  It's been done before, with some astrophysics paper where I answered a stat question here and they put me in a footnote somewhere in the paper!  Thanks!

Comment: @OmidMadani - I've updated the answer with a sketch of the proof that is far more accessible than the paper.  I hope it helps!

Comment: Wonderful. I hope I'll have a good draft in ~2 months, and I'll ping
you, for just fyi (And you might see how the ideas are used.. or misused!). I
work on large-scale online multiclass learning (unfortunately,
not on astrophysics!).

I had come across the Rao-Blackwellization concept before, but it is
another matter to see its actual use first hand on one's own problem!!
your post/pointers and accessible proof have led to a good deal of
education on my part!  I've begun to see a bit of how RBT works and could be used (also Lehmann–Scheffé).. definitely powerful tools! Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm looking forward to it; it's always great to see this stuff used elsewhere than on this site (or in classes!)